# UITableView size in both i0S7 and iOS5

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am having trouble getting my table view to size correctly on 3.5 inch iPhone between the two iOSs.

I have a tabbar (native).  I cannot use auto layout because its not compatible with iOS versions < 6.0. So Xcode tells me.

If I size for iOS 7 it gets cut off by the tab bar so i move it up but then it is in the middle of the screen for iOS 5.  and visa-versa.  Not to mention when I go and try it on a 4 inch screen.

The Autosizing Attribute in Xcode IB seems to be no help either. (Not the checkbox the lines)

In the pic below this is set for iOS 7 running it on iOS 5.  If I move it to the bottom of the black, which is not the bottom of the screen, it will be underneath the tab bar when ran.

I have played a round for some time with different configurations but I cannot seem to hit it right.  What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

Either set the tab bar translucency to NO

```
if ([self.tabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)])
        [self.tabBarController.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

or put this in your viewDidLoad in your controller

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
```

Comment: While the first one did not work the second one was perfect.  May I ask where did you find this?  If in the docs can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is found in the Apple Docs. There also some blog posts about it that explain it better probably. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html